# google maps pan to

Tags: javascript, google-maps, pan

Been struggling all day with setting a pan to in google maps from a text link. It looks like the id of the map itself isnt being passed through to the function but I have tried a number of things with no joy.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var home = new google.maps.LatLng(4.915833, 10.195313);
    function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 2,
            center: home,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            panControl: true,
            panControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
            },
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
            },
            scaleControl: false,
            streetViewControl: true,
            streetViewControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
            }
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        setMarkers(map, destinations);
        clickroute(map);
    }
    var destinations = [
        ['Marbella', 36.509937, -4.886352],
        ['Algarve', 37.016945, -7.928728],
        ['London', 51.508129, -0.128005],
        ['Istanbul', 41.00527, 28.97696],
        ['Whistler', 50.116168, -122.959423]
    ];
    function setMarkers(map, locations) {
        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/marker.png',
        new google.maps.Size(41, 63),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0));
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var destination = locations[i];
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(destination[1], destination[2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: destination[0]
            });
        }
    }
    function clickroute(lati, long) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.433373, -0.712251);
        map.panTo(latLng);
    }
</script> 

<li onclick="clickroute()">test</li>
```

Any possible ideas on what could cause the issue? I get a js error with

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'panTo'
```

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 19, accepted):

@onemach is correct.

1.
You have to declare the `map` as a global variable at the beginning of javascript. Just do a `var map;` declaration immediately after `<script type="text/javascript">` tag.

2.
And at the same time your map initialization should be changed to

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions); // without the 'var'
```

3. Your calling `clickroute()` onClick of `<li>` without parameters. So change the definition of  `clickroute()` like this :

```
function clickroute() { //just omit the 'lati' and 'long'
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.433373, -0.712251);
    map.panTo(latLng);
}
```

Now clicking on the `test` `<li>` your map will move to point (51.433373, -0.712251)

Answer (score 4):

`clickroute(map);` is incompatible with the definition

```
function clickroute(lati, long) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.433373, -0.712251);
    map.panTo(latLng);
}
```

I guess what you want it

```
function clickroute(map) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.433373, -0.712251);
    map.panTo(latLng);
}
```

UPDATE:

I am confused what exactly do you want.

`onclick=clickroute()` does not pass any arguments to the function.

Also there is no global `map` in clickroute.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply, still no joy with that and same error :(